# Hadoop: How to enable compression of intermediate data via contemporary API (2.7+)?

Tags: java, hadoop, compression, cloud

I'm finding a ton of advice on how to enable intermediate data compression using the deprecated API, but I'm not hitting anything current. I've poked around the API a bit but haven't spotted any obvious equivalents, though I'm still getting up to speed so obviously there's a lack of familiarity at play too.

Here's one example I ran across:

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(new Configuration(), MyJob.class);
conf.set("mapreduce.compress.map.output", "true");
conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compression.codec", 
         "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
```

The datasets involved are large enough to push the hdfs nodes into safe mode if compression isn't used, so relying on users to supply the cli parameters carries unacceptable risk (there isn't nearly as much available storage as there should be, but that's out of my hands). I need a pure coding solution. How does one enabling compression and setting the codecs in 2.7+?

A minimal code example, or an outline of the relevant parts of the API, would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be good if you can share what you have tested so far.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting; this is a known problem on this cluster. I am attempting to preemptively avoid taking down the cluster while testing.

Comment: It might be useful to see what deprecated properties you're finding, then someone may know the alternatives. And by compression, you can mean like Snappy & LZO?

Comment: Example posted. And yes, Snappy, LZO, I still need to look into what gives me the best compression ratio for the overhead.

Comment: It looks like the Configuration class is what I need to use. I'll post a solution once I've made sure it works. Also worth noting that a lot of the examples I found didn't bother to show 'conf' being declared, so for all I know that's been the practice all along, aside from some oddballs.